# Insert variable to temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I insert declared var into temp table?

```
DECLARE   @ConcatString VARCHAR(4000)
SELECT   @ConcatString = COALESCE(@ConcatString + ', ', '') + LanguageName FROM EmployeeLanguage  where  EmployeeId=10504
SELECT   @ConcatString AS Language

GO

DECLARE @T1 TABLE (
Item1 BigInt,
Item2 VARCHAR(200)
)
INSERT INTO @T1 select 1,(SELECT   @ConcatString AS Language ) as t

select * from @T1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `GO` statement.  It separates the query into two batches, and variables are only scoped to the batch they're created in.

You also don't need the sub-select.  Just do the following:

```
Insert Into @T1 
       (Item1, Item2)
Select 1, @ConcatString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes to the query

```
1. Remove the keyword GO.
2. Item2 VARCHAR(200) column size to VARCHAR(4000)

     if @ConcatStringlength exceed the current  Item2 VARCHAR(200)
```

- ***else error : String or binary data would be truncated.
     The statement has been terminated.***